# How to upload file to google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud

Cloudwok was great service to backup my files to google drive.
But Cloudwok is no longer in operation since April 2nd. Is there any service I can use instead of the Cloudwok?

Comment: You could use the API from google it self: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

Comment: @RonNabuurs Thanks. I will try to use it.